# php: how to sort user array with ids in correct order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am stuck with this, and I can't figure out the solution.

I have 2 arrays:

```
$user_names = array();
$user_ids = array();
```

Which look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Peter
    [2] => Anna
)

Array
(
    [0] => 67
    [1] => 68
    [2] => 73
)
```

I wanted to sort this array by $user_names with **sort($user_names)** but when I sort the user names then my user_ids are not matching up..

So if I wanted to print "User: John with id: X" after sorting user_names my ids don't match. I am dead stuck with this...

Answer (score 0):

You can combine id and names to one array and sort that array with asort to preserve the keys.

```
$user_names = ["John", "Peter", "Anna"];
$user_ids = [67,68,73];

$users = array_combine($user_ids, $user_names);
asort($users);

Var_dump($users);
```

Now key is the userid and value is the username.
This can easily be echoed with a foreach.

https://3v4l.org/FJeLg